# Is it possible to generate energy by exploiting the hydrostatic pressure gradient?

Tags: fluid-statics, applied-physics

Is there any way to harness the hydrostatic pressure  gradient to generate energy?
The pressure at the surface of an ocean is atmospheric pressure.As we descend down the ocean, the pressure increases .After a point, the pressure will be very high.Why cant we use this pressure difference to do work?

Comment: Doing work means moving a force through a distance. I can't see how your pressure difference can be made to do work.

Comment: Fluids at high pressure can crush metals(isostatic pressing, work done is the strain energy). Steam at high pressure, when allowed to expand through a turbine, it rotates the turbine.High pressure fluids push and pull heavy loads in hydraulic systems.Similarly is there any way to use the static pressure gradient?Is there any existing system which does it?Is it at least possible?

Comment: The problem with your hydrostatic pressure difference is that there's no way of using the pressure difference to drive a turbine because you can't put the low pressure one side of the turbine and high pressure the other side, as far as I can see!

Answer (score 2):

We can... We do.

Consider a high dam; one in which the water is very deep behind the dam, and thus with a high pressure at the bottom.

Punch a hole in the dam near the bottom, attach a turbine-generator, and start selling energy as the water flows through at high velocity.

Things become a little more complicated when the reservoir is quite shallow, like Lake Erie above Niagara Falls.  But the turbines at the generating stations at Niagara are at the *bottom* of Niagara Falls. The penstocks carrying water from above the Falls to the turbines could be considered a "deep part of Lake Erie", with the required high pressure at the bottom to generate lots of energy, as long as they keep getting filled from above...

Comment: indeed.  in the ocean scenario mentioned in the question you could deploy a dam as a tidal barrier.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to generate energy by exploiting the hydrostatic
>   pressure gradient?

Although the term "energy generation" is common, in daily life, the energy is not really generated but rather converted from one form to another.

For instance, if I lift a rock, the chemical energy stored in my body got converted to the potential energy of the rock. If, then I drop the rock, its potential energy is converted to the kinetic energy and, when the rock lands, its kinetic energy is converted to heat. Usual stuff.

Similarly, when work is performed, it involves transfer of energy from one object to another, with or without conversion of energy from one form to another.

**So, what energy could be extracted and transferred from the ocean?**

We can say that the water on the surface of the ocean has some positive potential energy relative to the bottom of the ocean, but that energy cannot be realized, since, using QM analogy, all lower energy levels are already occupied.

The only way to make the water in the ocean to do work is to lift it and then let it go. But, in this case, the original energy, required for the lifting, would come not from the potential of the water, but form some other source - similar to the scenario with a rock.

To summarize, the potential energy stored in the ocean could not be transferred to some object or converted to another form of energy or be used to perform some useful work, without someone spending some other energy upfront.